# How to find installation path for packages installed through apt-get in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, python, eclipse, apt-get

I have been installing python modules using `apt-get` which works great using the console or launching files from the command line. However I am using Eclipse for easier organisation of files.

Eclipse doesn't automatically find new modules like terminal does, so I was wondering if there was a way of finding out the install path which an `apt-get` command uses?

I just realised that you can delete the python eclipse looks at and reconfigure it to fix my particular problem. It would still be useful for me to find the installation path though!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`dpkg -L <package_name>` will give you a list of all files in a package. Usually python packages install to /usr/lib/python/ (ie: /usr/lib/python2.7/).